# Objective-C XCode10.1 how to fix default indentation for methods in a file?

Tags: objective-c, autocomplete, indentation, xcode10

I have inherited a legacy Objective-C code and am seeing that by default the editor indents function definitions by 4 spaces. I expected top level functions within a class to be indented by 0 spaces (aligned with the window edge). I do not see any per-file settings that would modify the default indentation behavior.

How do I fix indentation for Objective-C code to align top level class methods with the left edge of the window?

The file type is set as Default - Objective-C Source

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode's menu bar, you can use Editor > Structure > Re-Indent (⌃ + I) on a per file basis.

Comment: The default indentation is set wrong and reindent does not fix that

Comment: Oh. That's weird. I've never seen an indent rule that would cause something like that to happen. Interested to find out what would cause that.